# jQuery resizable trigger resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I want to `resize` a resizable, draggable image on `document.ready`.

The problem is that if I change the width of the image the rest of resizable/draggable will be broken.

Starting demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8VY52/
`$('#image').width(50);` : http://jsfiddle.net/8VY52/141/

Is there any `resize` event that must be triggered?

Answer (score 3):

Why not resize the image after the document is ready then apply the resizable function:

```
$('#draggableHelper').draggable();

$(function(){
    $('#image').width(50);
    $('#image').resizable();
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8VY52/145/

If you want to do this on a button click event here is a working example:

```
$('#draggableHelper').draggable();

$(function(){
    $('#image').width(50);
    $('#image').resizable();

    $('#resize-button').on('click',function(){
        var size = 150; //Or what ever you want
        $('#image').resizable('destroy');
        $('#image').width(size);
        $('#image').resizable();
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8VY52/147/

Comment: That was only an example. I need to trigger a resize every time a user clicks a button.

Comment: so resize it then reapply the resizable to it. That should do the trick

Comment: I also had to reset CSS height to "auto" for the image to keep its proportions when changing width. `$(this).css({height:'auto'});` http://jsfiddle.net/8VY52/149/

Comment: @showdev I didnt do that because the OP has the image to be re-size on all axis meaning that it wont necessarily maintain proportions

Comment: Gotcha. That makes sense.